# How can I stop the Window Confirm Method from pausing my mouse event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I am using the example from here http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033 I am attempting to change this:

```
function click(d) {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // click suppressed
    d = toggleChildren(d);
    update(d);
    centerNode(d);
}
```

to this block of code:

```
function click2(d) {
    //d3.event.preventDefault()
    //d = toggleChildren(d);
    var msg = "Would you like to re root the table at this node?";
    var resp = confirm(msg)
    if(resp == true){
        //reroot
    }
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
}
```

However when I click the node and then go to click the confirmation window that pops up. The SVG tree follows my cursor as if the confirm window was pausing my mouse up event until after. I was wondering how I could get it to stop it from doing that.

Comment: Maybe it should be a `mousedown` event instead of `click` event.

Comment: It is currently under a contextmenu click since there is no notion of right click that I can find in D3 so I can't change that to mousedown event